Jetpack Compose - BasicTextfield decorationBox behavior - innerTextField is too small when wrapped in a row
I have a problem with the BasicTextfield.
I have created an example here to illustrate my problem.
I want to display the content right-aligned in the textfield and use the decorationBox for further customization. The problem is, if I embed the innerTextField in a row, the width is reduced to the standard width (see textfield 03).
How can the innerTextField() be used in a row without changing the width?
It should fill the maximum width.
Run on Android Studio
Result of the code - please view
Here the example:
Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(20.dp)) {

BasicTextField(
    modifier = Modifier
        .border(1.dp, Color.Magenta),
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    textStyle = TextStyle(
        textAlign = TextAlign.End
    ),
)


BasicTextField(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .border(1.dp, Color.Blue),
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    textStyle = TextStyle(
        textAlign = TextAlign.End
    ),
    decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
            innerTextField()
    },
)

BasicTextField(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .border(1.dp, Color.Green),
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    textStyle = TextStyle(
        textAlign = TextAlign.End
    ),
    decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
        Row(Modifier.border(1.dp, Color.Red)){
            innerTextField()
        }
    },
)}

